# slow script trying to find unique values in list

Tags: python

I've got a problem in Python:
I want to find how many UNIQUE `a**b` values exist if:
    `2 ≤ a ≤ 100`and `2 ≤ b ≤ 100`?

I wrote the following script, but it's too slow on my laptop (and doesnt even produce the results):

```
List=[]
a = 2
b = 2
c = pow(a, b)
while b != 101:
    while a != 101:
        if List.count(c) == 0:
            List.append(c) 
            a += 1
    b += 1
print len(List)
```

Is it good? Why is it slow?

Comment: What have you done to attempt to debug this?

Comment: You forgot to recalculate the value of `c` in every step of the loop. It's slow because you do around 100,000 iterations, in which you need to recalculate `c`, check if it exists in `List` and add it to it if needed. That's a lot of operations. However no immediate simplier solution strikes to my head at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

This code doesn't work; it's an infinite loop because of the way you don't increment `a` on every iteration of the loop.  After you fix that, you still won't get the right answer because you never reset `a` to 2 when `b` reaches `101`.

Then, `List` will ever contain only `4` because you set `c` outside the loop to `2 ** 2` and never change it inside the loop. And when you fix *that* it'll still be slower than it really needs to be because you are reading the entire list each time through to get the count, and as it gets longer, that takes more and more time.

You generally should use `in` rather than `count` if you just need to know if an item is in a list, since it will stop as soon as it finds the the item, but in this specific instance you should be using a `set` anyway, since you are looking for unique values. You can just `add` to the set without checking to see whether the item is already in it.

Finally, using `for` loops is more readable than using `while` loops.

```
result = set()
for a in xrange(2, 101):
    for b in xrange(2, 101):
        result.add(a ** b)
print len(result)
```

This takes less than a second on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your script is slow and doesn't return a value is that you have created an infinite loop. You need to dedent the `a += 1` line by one level, otherwise, after the first time through the inner `while` loop `a` will not get incremented again.

There are some additional issues with the script that have been pointed out in the comments, but this is what is responsible for the issues your are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not good, since it does not produce correct results. As the comment by @grael pointed out, you do not recalculate the value of `c` inside the loop, so you are counting only one value over and over again. There are also other problems, as other people have noted.

Your code is not fast for several reasons.

1. You are using a brute-force method. The answer can be found more simply by using number theory and combinatorics. Look at the prime factorization of each number between 2 and 100 and consider the prime factorization of each power of that number. You never need to calculate the complete number--the prime factorization is enough. I'll leave the details to you but this would be much faster.
2. You are rolling your own loop, but it is faster to use python's. Loop `a` and `b` with:

   ```
   for a in range(2,101):
       for b in range(2,101):
           c = pow(a, b)
           # other code here
   ```

This code uses the built-in capabilities of the language and should be faster. This also avoids your errors since it is simpler.

3. You use a *very* slow method to see if a number has already been calculated. Your `if List.count(c) == 0` must check every previous number to see if the current number has been seen. This will become very slow when you have already seen thousands of numbers. It is much faster to keep the already-seen numbers in a set rather than a list. Checking if a number is in a set is *much faster* than using `count()` on a list.

Try combining all these suggestions. As another answer shows, just using the last two probably suffice.